# make a bootable hello world program in rust

Tags: operating-system, rust, bootable

I have recently come across Rust and found that one can easily write system code in Rust without touching assembly.
I just want to make a bootable hello world program out of my hello.rs code:

```
fn main() {
    println!("Hello World");
}
```

Is there a way to make this Rust code bootable?

Comment: Not sure what you mean...

Comment: I want to make an iso of this program like a bootloader

Comment: redox os is written in rust: https://github.com/redox-os/redox

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is an blog about [Writing an OS in Rust](https://os.phil-opp.com/), where first steps are about booting and printing some stuff to screen using only Rust.

It's an advanced topic, so I wouldn't recommand starting with writing an OS, execpt if you want to discover how an OS work.